# function created in React render return, good or bad

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've been asked questions like, is it good or bad to have functions in the Functional Components return an object?

like

```
export const Button = ({...props}) => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div
           onClick={()=> setIsChecked(true)}>
            <div>
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

So is it good to have this in return?

I know that on a component class if you have a function in render, it will get created every time, which tends to be a bad pattern.

But this is a functional component, it gets called every time on render, so does that brings any harm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...so does that brings any harm?

Not really, no, and it's standard practice with React hooks. JavaScript engines are **very** good at allocating and releasing objects, and the function's underlying code will get reused (not that there's much of it :-) ).

Hooks are actually somewhat predicated on the idea that JavaScript engines handle this well. Even `useCallback` still involves creating a new function **every time**, all `useCallback` does is give you back the previous version of the function if none of the dependencies changed, it can't prevent the creation (and then instant discarding) of the function you pass it.

**That said**, if you had a lot of these like your example that don't rely on state and wanted to avoid creating unnecessary functions each time, you could use a ref:

```
// If you really wanted to optimize it away
export const Button = ({...props}) => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    const fnsRef = useRef(null);
    if (!fnsRef.current) {
        fnsRef.current = {
            setIsCheckedTrue: () => setIsChecked(true),
            // ...
        };
    }

    return (
        <div
           onClick={fnsRef.current.setIsCheckedTrue}>
            <div>
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

You can use a ref when you would have put something as an instance property on the component instance with a `class` component. The above works because `fnsRef.current` will only be `null` the **first** time your function is called for a given component instance, and because the setter function you get from `useState` is stable.

But again, that's a micro-optimization and so doing it prematurely just complicates the code. Do it if and when you see an issue with memory allocations/cleanup slowing things down.

Answer (score 1):

On it's own react is pretty performant, so you will not notice any slowdowns or anything,

As T.J. Crowser pointed out,`useCallback` is about avoiding making child components re-render; you may want to use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook:

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
});

const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

> This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components
> that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g.
> shouldComponentUpdate).
>
> useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps).

Or, you are using some expensive calculation to set state pf a component, like [Persist state with local storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTP2gi7e3k8), you may want to  [pass an updater function to `useState()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
  return initialState;
});
```

Comment: That `useCallback` example doesn't do anything to reduce the cost of an expensive calcuation (that would be `useMemo` where the function passed to `useMemo` does something expensive; `useCallback` is `useMemo` where the function *doesn't* do anything expensive), but *does* increase the amount of work the function has to do every time it's called. `useCallback` doesn't help the function it's in run more efficiently, it helps *child elements* (if any) that you're passing the function to avoid re-rendering by giving them a stable callback.

Comment: And whenever those `childs` re-renders, does not the function will re-render? if not wrapped in `useCallback? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: `useCallback` is about avoiding making child components re-render. It isn't about reducing the cost of an expensive calcuation as you've said in the answer. That's what I was saying above.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you on that one, it is for avoiding un-necessary re-renders. My intention behind that statement was this one, now you highlighted it, I will edit the answer